# symlinks creates duplicate folder name

Tags: symlink, aws, wordpress

I have purchased an ebs volume to keep all my wordpress uploads. My wordpress files are in `/var/www/html` and in order to link between the upload folder here and in ebs volume, i created a symlink as follows

`ln -s /ebs1/uploads /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads`

right now, when i access an image in the uplods folders, there is extra `uploads` comes in the URL

`www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/uploads/2016/12/flower.jpg`

is there any solution for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are creating a link to `uploads` in `uploads`.  Do you want `ln -s /ebs1/uploads /var/www/html/wp-content` ?

Comment: Now it comes like `www.example.com//ebs1/uploads/2016/12/flower.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 forms of ln command. The form that you used creates a a symlink inside /var/.../uploads named /var/.../uploads/uploads to your /ebs1/uploads directory which is itself a symlink to /var/.../uploads (Checked it myself).

The solution is to use this form of ln:

```
ln -s -T  /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads /ebs1/uploads
```